# Render html based on device type

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my project I use a responsive css so the layout adapt itself to the device. But I need to change the render of a unordered list (used by a carousel). Basically for desktop and iPad I'm actually render the list as this:

```
<div id="carousel">
<div id="slide_A">
    <ul class="carousel">
        <li><div class="item">AAA</div></li>
        <li><div class="item">BBB</div></li>
        <li><div class="item">CCC</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="slide_B">
    <ul class="carousel">
        <li><div class="item">DDD</div></li>
        <li><div class="item">EEE</div></li>
        <li><div class="item">FFF</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Otherwise for device such iPhone the code should be this:

```
<div id="carousel">
<div id="slide_A">
    <ul class="carousel">
        <li><div class="item">AAA</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="slide_B">
    <ul class="carousel">
        <li><div class="item">BBB</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="slide_C">
    <ul class="carousel">
        <li><div class="item">CCC</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>  
....
```

Is there a chance to detect server-side (c#) the current user agent or device type?
thanks

Comment: Why exactly? Chances are theres another way to do what you're trying to do...

Comment: Because on iPhone I need to add a slide for each div thus the scroller show a picture per page ( if I would show 6 images they would appear too little)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UserAgent in the request header. This contains the information about the browsers, devices etc. You have to find the required device within this user agent string to verify whether the request is coming from the specified device or not.

For example use the following function to check if the request is coming from any mobile device

```
public static bool IsMobileDevice()
        {
            string u = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
            Regex b = new Regex(@"android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
            Regex v = new Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\\-(n|u)|c55\\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\\-5|g\\-mo|go(\\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\\-(m|p|t)|hei\\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\\-c|ht(c(\\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\\-|\\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\\-|e\\/|\\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\\-w|m3ga|m50\\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\\-g|qa\\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\\-[2-7]|i\\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\\-|oo|p\\-)|sdk\\/|se(c(\\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\\-|shar|sie(\\-|m)|sk\\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\\-|v\\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\\-|tdg\\-|tel(i|m)|tim\\-|t\\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\\-|m3|m5)|tx\\-9|up(\\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\\-|2|g)|yas\\-|your|zeto|zte\\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
            if ((b.IsMatch(u) || v.IsMatch(u.Substring(0, 4))))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to see if it is an iPad:

```
bool isIpad = Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("ipad");
```